# query to aggregat data by day to generate charts - rows unkown

Tags: mysql

I started building a search engine monitor. I'm pulling data from the google rest api into a mysql database with the following fields: date, search-keyword, domain, url, position.

Now I got into trouble querying and outputting the data for charting. The results go up and down, new results from google come into the list which haven't been there on the first day. However for charting I have to assign the first days at least blank values to output a chart.

What I do right now: First I select every domain showing up in the period. Lets say the for the keyword searchengine I get the domains wikipedia.org, ixquick.com, yahoo.com, searchenginewatch.com When I make another request for ever domain to query an array of rankings grouped by day. leading to the ...

**Problem: Is where any query (mysql/nosql) which returns for each day an average and if where is no row a default value e.g. blank?**

Result should look like:

```
dates={01/01/2014,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,...,31}
wikipedie={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...,1}
yahoo = {"","",7,5,3,3,3,...,3}
```

Comment: Please give an example of the data you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a date table, select the date range you'd like, and outer join your data to it, filling in 0s for values that do not exist for a given term/date.

Edit:
Some more details.

1) Create a table that has a row for every date +- 10 years (or whatever is appropriate). You can make this one column if you'd like, or many columns (date, month, year, etc.). The second approach makes this extensible if you want to summarize by various rollups in the future.

2) Outer join your table to the date table and use a NVL statement to coerce any null averages to 0.

3) Profit!

Comment: This is the approach I always like to take.  You may want to elaborate with an example.

Comment: Were my first thoughts too @DNadel. However I was wondering whether there is a native sql statement for this which performce better than a join?

Comment: Just a thought? Has any other database like couch, mongo or hadoop such a function with map/reduce?

Comment: I'd say a nicely indexed table with date will be just as good as a built in function. I don't know of one off the top of my head. And I can't speak to M/R side of things- I'm more of a Oracle/MySQL kinda guy :)

Answer (score 0):

If your results are grouped by date, how can MySQL know there's (for example) 31 days in that month?

On the other hand, you can somehow fill the holes in PHP by loop through the array and fill a zero if the value does not exist.